# Boost spirit x3 - how to parse nested structures?

Tags: c++, boost, boost-spirit-x3

I try to parse

```
list<char> fldName
```

I used the nested structures. But I have a trouble with parsing when one structure nested in other. Look at the sollowing minimal sample code:

```
#include <boost/config/warning_disable.hpp>
#include <boost/spirit/home/x3.hpp>
#include <boost/fusion/include/adapt_struct.hpp>
#include <string>
#include <string_view>

using namespace std::string_view_literals;
using namespace boost::spirit::x3;
namespace ascii = boost::spirit::x3::ascii;

namespace client::ast
{
    struct ValidType
    {
        std::string Name;
        std::string SubName1;
        std::string SubName2;
    };

    struct StructField
    {
        ValidType Type;
        std::string Name;
    };

}   // namespace client::ast

BOOST_FUSION_ADAPT_STRUCT(client::ast::ValidType,
    Name, SubName1, SubName2
)

BOOST_FUSION_ADAPT_STRUCT(client::ast::StructField,
    Type, Name
)

namespace client::parser
{
    using ascii::char_;

    template <typename T> static auto as = [](auto p) { return rule<struct tag, T> {"as"} = p; };
#define STRING(x) as<std::string>(x)

    rule<class ValidType, ast::ValidType> const ValidType = "ValidType";
    rule<class StructField, ast::StructField> const StructField = "StructField";

    auto const ValidName = lexeme[(alpha | char_('_')) > *(alnum | char_('_'))];

    auto const ValidType_SecondPart = char('<') > STRING(ValidName) > ('>' | ',' > STRING(ValidName) > '>');
    auto const ValidType_def = STRING(ValidName) > -(ValidType_SecondPart);

    auto const StructField_def = ValidType_def > STRING(ValidName);

    BOOST_SPIRIT_DEFINE(ValidType);
    BOOST_SPIRIT_DEFINE(StructField);

}   // namespace client::parser

int main()
{
    using boost::spirit::x3::ascii::space;
    auto theData = R"(
                list<char> fldName
        )"sv;
    using client::parser::StructField;
    client::ast::StructField fld;

    bool result = phrase_parse(theData.begin(), theData.end(), StructField, space, fld);
    return result;
}
```

I receive following error:

```
Error   C2338   Size of the passed attribute is less than expected
```

But I have no idea what is wrong. Its looks like boost::spirit::x3 have a bug with parsing nested structures.

Is there exists any way how to parse nested stuctures?

**Answer** - **ValidType_def** -> **ValidType** :

```
auto const StructField_def = ValidType_def > STRING(ValidName); 
-> 
auto const StructField_def = ValidType > STRING(ValidName);
```

Comment: `auto const StructField_def = ValidType_def > STRING(ValidName);` -> `auto const StructField_def = ValidType > STRING(ValidName);`

Comment: @llonesmiz, OMG it works! But ..... wow! Now I get how it should be. Thank you very much!